# Populating tableView with data obtained from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my scenario:

1) datasource to my tableView is an array called `books` - `var books:[BookItem]`

2) I populate `books` anytime some data in db has changed

3) I create `BookItem` by joining data from two tables, since `BookItem` consists of some user-specific data and some general data about the book itself.

I wrote a method called `createDataSource` that takes care of populating `books` array with `BookItem`s

```
func createDataSource()
{
    self.books.removeAll()

    let userId:String = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "UserId") as! String

    let bookForUserRef = self.ref!.child("users").child(userId).child("userbooks")

    bookForUserRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var i = 0

        for element in snapshot.children
        {
            i = i + 1

            let item:FIRDataSnapshot = element as! FIRDataSnapshot
            let postDict = item.value as! [String : AnyObject]
            let key = item.key

            let booksRef = self.ref!.child("books").child(key)
            booksRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

                let bookItem = (snapshot as! FIRDataSnapshot).value as! [String : AnyObject]
                let id = booksRef.key
                print(id)
                let record = [bookItem["title"] as! String, bookItem["author"] as! String, "0", "\(bookItem["pagesCount"] as! Int)"]

                let item = BookItem(title: bookItem["title"] as! String, author: bookItem["author"] as! String, pagesCount: bookItem["pagesCount"] as! Int, currentPage: postDict["currentPage"] as! Int, language: bookItem["language"] as! String, year: nil, ISBN: nil, id: id, added: postDict["added"] as? String ?? "21")
                self.books.append(item)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            })

        }

    })

}
```

**Anytime I call this method, all existing elements gets duplicated in `books` array.**

I thought it might have something to do with for loop, but after debugging it seems alright.

I suppose there is something specific with observers in firebase that duplicates the elements. I am rather new to firebase and I suppose my approach might be a bit messed and confusing.

**What should be modified in the `createDataSource()` method, to get rid of elements duplication?**

**Also, is my approach to working with firebase and tableView correct?**

Comment: You should take a look at your loops and observers, it looks a bit weird. Have you tried to put `self.books.removeAll()` inside at the beginning of the first value observer? If that works you should also move `self.tableView.reloadData()` to the end of the first observer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ntoonio comment I got it solved

```
 func createDataSource()
 {

    let userId:String = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "UserId") as! String

    let bookForUserRef = self.ref!.child("users").child(userId).child("userbooks")

    bookForUserRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var i = 0
        self.books.removeAll()
        for element in snapshot.children
        {
            i = i + 1

            let item:FIRDataSnapshot = element as! FIRDataSnapshot
            let postDict = item.value as! [String : AnyObject]
            let key = item.key

            let booksRef = self.ref!.child("books").child(key)
            booksRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

                let bookItem = (snapshot as! FIRDataSnapshot).value as! [String : AnyObject]
                let id = booksRef.key
                print(id)
                let record = [bookItem["title"] as! String, bookItem["author"] as! String, "0", "\(bookItem["pagesCount"] as! Int)"]

                let item = BookItem(title: bookItem["title"] as! String, author: bookItem["author"] as! String, pagesCount: bookItem["pagesCount"] as! Int, currentPage: postDict["currentPage"] as! Int, language: bookItem["language"] as! String, year: nil, ISBN: nil, id: id, added: postDict["added"] as? String ?? "21")
                self.books.append(item)
                self.tableView.reloadData()


            })

        }

    })

}
```

Comment: While this works, treating a collection of books as a single key/value pair (i.e. object) is discouraged. Should utilize [working with lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data).

Comment: @Kato could you provide the correct approach to dealing with lists?